# Terminal has error different from actual code

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I made a reddit bot following [this guide](http://progur.com/2016/09/how-to-create-reddit-bot-using-praw4.html). I own a raspberry pi running raspbian. I am using Python3 IDLE. At the end of the tutorial it says "Save the file, and exit your code editor. From the command line, you can run the bot using the following command: python3 mybot.py". I did that and got this error:

```
python example.py
File "example.py", line 1
    Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11) 
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My problem? That isn't in my code.The first two lines of my code are

```
import praw
bot = praw.Reddit(user_agent='example'),
```

Why would it give an error for a nonexsistent first line? Any help?

Comment: From the same terminal, what do you see if you run `cat exemple.py`?

Comment: Does your code contains the line: `Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11) `? I get similar error by pasting it in a Python file: http://ideone.com/U2rTO6

Comment: @litelite when entering that it gives Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import praw

Comment: Seems like the file you are trying to run contains the output of a python interactive session... Are you sure you are running the correct file? you can type `pwd` to get the current directory

Comment: @litelite in the python editor i am using when i run my program another window pops up with that text with ===RESTART=== under it. Maybe that's the problem? If so, I don't know where/how to write the program correctly.

Comment: There has to be something in *example.py*. Try pasting your code in a text editor, then run the script from the terminal `$ python3.4 example /full/path/to/script` include the full path of your script just to *make sure.

Answer (score 0):

`Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11)` is the header of the application when started in interactive mode.

It seems that it is started without taking in account the argument `example.py` that you provided.

You should investigate around that. Would writing `$(python example.py)` work any better?

Otherwise you can still add a `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line of your file, and try to start it with `./example.py` (might require a `chmod +x`)

Comment: Don't hesitate to mark it solved if it helped you, so other users experiencing the same issue can know it helped.